# JQuery-Validation - using rules method on selected ID, why does the name attribute have to be present on the element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, name-attribute

I'm a little confused about the [JQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) behavior.

If I have the following JQuery:

```
$('#form1').validate({
    /* other validation */
});

$('#txt1').rules("add",
{
    required: true,
    messages: { required: 'This is required!' }
});
```

and the following text input, with an id but no name attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
```

No required message pops up on the text box.

However, if I add a name attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="anything"/>
```

It validates it just fine.

Why is that?  Since I'm using the [rules("add", rules) method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) on an ID selector, why does it need the name attribute present in order to associate rules to the element?  Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `name` attribute is required on the element firstly because that's what jQuery validate uses internally as a key for each field, and secondly because the `name` attribute is required on `input` elements to ensure the page validates to the specified DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply the rules using the id then use like this,

```
$(function () {
  var $field = $("#id_field").attr("name");
  var $params = {debug:false, rules:{}, messages:{}};
  $params['rules'][$field] = {"required": true, "rule": ["params"]};
  $params['messages'][$field] = "error message";

  $("#frm").validate($params);
});
```

Comment: Can you expand on the explanation here, how does this code allow the validator to find the elements based on the id attribute?

Comment: OP is asking *"**why** does the name attribute have to be present on the element?"* - So instead of answering the actual question, you programmatically find and copy the `name` attribute into the method. Completely pointless - if you have a `name` then use the `name`.  Otherwise you can use the `.rules()` method to assign rules by `id`, even though a unique `name` on each field element is still a mandatory requirement for this plugin.  However, OP wants to to know if he can avoid using `name` attributes altogether and that's just impossible with this plugin.