# jQuery Validate by ID and form group

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate by id and not input name because my input name is data[name]. I also have a rule to allow one or both fields.

I can add the rules with id but I cannot combine both rules. Is there a way.

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control contact-method" name="data[email]" placeholder="Email">
<input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control contact-method" name="data[phone]" placeholder="Phone">
```

Js Code:

```
$('#requestDemo').validate({  // <- attach '.validate()' to your form
    debug: false,
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    rules: {
        phoneInput: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".contact-method"]
        },
        emailInput: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".contact-method"]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Last post here gives the solution it seems? https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-validating-on-input-id-instead-of-name , another example would probably be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145283/jquery-validation-using-rules-method-on-selected-id-why-does-the-name-attribu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also have a rule to allow one or both fields.

I don't see how your `require_from_group` rule is going to work when you're not using the `contact-method` class anyplace in your HTML markup.  You'll need to add this `class`...

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control contact-method" name="data[email]" placeholder="Email">
<input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control contact-method" name="data[phone]" placeholder="Phone">
```

---

> I need to validate by `id` and not input `name` because my input `name` is `data[name]`

There are two workarounds...

1. [When the `name` contains special characters like dots or brackets, you would simply surround the `name` with quotes](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots))...

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       $('#requestDemo').validate({
           ....
           rules: {
              "data[email]": {
                   require_from_group: [1, ".contact-method"]
               },
               ....
   ```

   **DEMO 1:  http://jsfiddle.net/umgjLvhd/**

---

2. Declare the rule using [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) instead of within `.validate()`...

   ```
   $('.contact-method').each(function() {
       $(this).rules('add', {
           require_from_group: [1, $(this)]
       });
   });
   ```

   **DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/mcotx2oh/**

---

**NOTE**:  No matter how you declare the rules, the `input` elements **must** still contain unique `name` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are facing is the special characters in the `name`, you can use a string literal in such cases as the object key like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#requestDemo').validate({ // <- attach '.validate()' to your form
    debug: true,
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    rules: {
      'data[email]': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".contact-method"]
      },
      'data[phone]': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".contact-method"]
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<form id="requestDemo" method="post" action="">
  <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control contact-method" name="data[email]" placeholder="Email">
  <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control contact-method" name="data[phone]" placeholder="Phone">

  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```